# Magento 2 - Show product data in front end using graphQL

Tags: magento2, graphql

I need to show Product Data (Name `SKU`)in front end using `graphQL` is this possible to show Product Data custom page in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's possible...
Create new template file and link in xml file where you want...
And Paste this codes in template file...

```
<?php
$query = '
    query {
    products(filter: {category_id: {eq: "2"}}) {
    items {
      name
      sku
    }
  }
}
';


$json = json_encode(['query' => $query]);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, '[YOUR END POINT]');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
     array(
            'User-Agent: PHP Script',
            'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization: bearer [YOUR TOKEN]' 
        )
    ); 

$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo "<pre>",var_dump($response),"</pre>";

?>
```